# About string, null character and strcmp

Tags: c, strcmp, null-terminated, c-strings

I created C program in microcontroller, and want to compare string in my C program with string that received from my PC, my program in PC using C#, and by default string in C# doesn't contain null character.

So, my c program doesn't automatically add null character in string that received from PC?

And does strcmp function can compare 2 strings, 1 string contain null character, and another one not contain null character?

Comment: `strcmp` requires both its arguments to be NUL-terminated

Comment: In C you have null if you don't have initialized your string variable

Comment: Just to add to Mr @CoolGuy's comment, mostly all the functions in `string.h` needs null-terminated arguments.

Comment: so, when my c program receive string from c# program to compare, i need to add null character manually?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Nop? So if you don't have initialized a String in C what will you get? I mean if you only declare your variable and don't call the constructor? Will you get directly trash inside your variable? I thought it was NULL

Comment: @acostela uninitialized variables have indeterminate value. it's not guaranteed to be 0 or NULL or anything like that. (also, there are no constructors in C.)

Comment: `NULL` != `null`; `null` == `NUL`

Comment: When you "receive" the string add the terminating `'\0'` right then.

Comment: What @pmg said. NUL-terminated means (in this context) both of your input strings have `'\0'` at the end. Whether you want to add it in C# or in C is up to you. I'd send the length of the string, the string and then add the NUL-termination on the C side.

Comment: That's how strings work in C, if it doesn't end with a `'\0'` it's not a string in C anymore.

Comment: Surely you are not simply passing the .Net string directly to the embedded system?  For a start it is a class not an array, and is in any event Unicode not a byte string.  Whatever you are doing to serialise the string and flatten it to ASCII surely can also add the nul terminator?  Either that or you use a length+unterminated string, then either the receiver could add the nul or you could use `memcmp` and a length comparison.

Comment: I have just noted the date on this question - it has repeatedly been "bumped by community user" whatever then means?  How do you even do that?  And why? As a question it has little merit if the OP has chosen not to engage by clearing the ambiguity since 2015!

Answer (score 0):

Defination of Strings in C (from Wikipedia) is

> A string is a contiguous sequence of code units terminated by the
>   first zero code (corresponding to the ASCII null character).

That said, without NUL character, you cannot use standard string functions like `strcmp()` or `strcpy()` and may end up corrupting memory.

You can do two things:
Add `Char.MinValue` at the end of string in your C# code before transmitting.

`string str = "Hello,World!" + Char.MinValue; // Add NUL`.

Or you can write your own string compare function like

```
int myStrcmp(char* str1, char* str2, int len)
{
    int retVal = 0,

    for(int loopcnt = 0; loopcnt < len; loopcnt++)
     {

          if((*str1) > (*str2))
           {
              retVal = -1;
               break;        
           }
          else if((*str1) < (*str2))
           {
              retVal = 1;
               break;                      
           }
           str1++;
           str2++;

     }
 return retVal;
}
```

But then, you will require length of string. If you already know the length, it's better and faster to add a NUL character manually. :-)

Comment: Thank you sir, maybe i will use string str = "Hello,World!" + Char.MinValue; 
In your function, what should the value for len variable? and how if i want to add null character from my c program?

Comment: @AntiMafia len is length of string (which you should know... without NUL) and to add NUL in your string, you know the length and you must be getting string in an array, so add 0x00 as the next element in array or reset your receive buffer with all 0x00 before you receive anything and repeat it for every reception

Comment: iam confuse sir. If the string which i want "testing\0", and the string i want to compare "test" (without null, because i get string from pc). So i will get return value 0?

Comment: If you pass string "testing" and "test" (irrespective of NUL to this function) and length as 4 (length of `test`), you will get 0 but if you pass length as 7 (length of `testing `) you will not get it. Try to understand this code.

Comment: Instead of coding your own "string comparison" function, there is a C library function for that: [memcmp](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/)

Comment: "_Try to understand this code._"? Perhaps you should try to understand the requirement.  For a correct comparison you would first need the compare the lengths.  Presumably the length of the incoming string is known.  It is also a rather efficient `memcmp`. Even is `memcmp` did not exist, all you need do is subtract `*str1` from `*str2` while the result is zero or `len` reached, and return the final result.  Besides it is academic, C# strings are .Net `String` objects in UTF-16.  There is far more to be resolved (or which the OP has not defined) than just the nul terminator.

Comment: ... typo:  "efficient" -> "inefficient".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have one null-terminated string, `const char *s1`, and another string, `const char *s2` (not necessarily null-terminated) and a length of the second string, `unsigned len2`, you can do the following to get a result similar to that of `strcmp()`:

```
    int result;
    unsigned len1 = strlen(s1);
    result = memcmp(s1, s2, (len1<len2) ? len1 : len2);
    if(result == 0 && len1 < len2) result = -1;
    if(result == 0 && len2 < len1) result = 1;
```

Comment: If the lengths differ, there is no need to do the `memcmp` - the strings are implicitly not the same. Also the OP has omitted information, C# strings are also UTF-16 and are objects of type `String`, not a simple byte array.

Comment: @Clifford If the string is in UTF-16, you are right that the OP has more problems than stated in the question. As stated in the answer, the problem which I understood from the OP description and wrote a solution for is: to compare a C-string and a character sequence with the same result as if the the character sequence had been 0-terminated and compared with `strcmp`. `memcmp` is still necessary if lengths differ to determine the lexicographical order.

Comment: @neilson true, for strcmp semantics.  But if at the application level it is a simple Boolean same/not same test (as is most often the case), then length is enough.  I guess we cannot know from this - the question as an [X-Y](https://xyproblem.info/) smell about it.

Comment: ... also just noted the date on this - apologies - I guess no one is concerned any longer, but for some reason it keeps getting "bumped" for no apparent reason I can see.

Comment: @Clifford Yes, I think I got caught the same way when I wrote this answer. I have now voted for closing the question as there is no need for it to keep taking focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string and you are not sure that it is null terminated, you can use `strncmp` instead and specify how many characters you want to compare without having to reach the null character.

[For more informations about `strncmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncmp.htm)

Answer (score 0):

> by default string in C# doesn't contain null character.

In C# `string` is an alias for the .Net `System.String` *class*.  It is not a simple 8-bit character array.  The internal representation it is true does not have a nul terminator (because it has a length attribute), but more importantly it is UTF-16 (Unicode) and will not compare in any event directly to an ASCII encoded string.

Clearly when passed from the PC to the embedded system, some sort of serialisation and conversion to ASCII must occur?  The simple solution is for that process to insert the nul.

If you cannot change the form of the data passed from the PC, then the string must have a known length?  Either passed in the data structure, or simply by counting received characters?  In that case it would be simple enough to add the nul on receipt?  In fact if the receiving buffer were zero initialised, and longer by at least 1 than the longest string to be received, then it will already be nul terminated.

The point is that C# `string` and C strings have completely different representations, and cannot be compared without conversion.  The nul terminator is the least issue.